# Azure Video Indexer player widget stopped working on mobile devices

Tags: azure-media-services, azure-video-indexer

The Azure Video Analyzer for Media (formerly Video Indexer) player widget has stopped working correctly on mobile devices.
In mobile the devices, the iframe-based widget shows the play button, but after it is clicked, it just does nothing and only keeps showing a black screen.
I already confirmed this issue happens even on new websites with just an index.html page and the widget: works on desktop, but does not work on mobile devices, it just to work before.

Edited.
It is failing on iOS 15.3.1, on both Safari and Chrome 98.0.4758.97.
Works on Android Emulator Pixel 5 API 30

Comment: I am still experiencing this issue, after comment by @NofarEdan Has anyone found a solution?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was a problem on Video Indexer side that is now fixed. Thanks for reaching out!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).